# What is the meaning of -//- sign?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics

[image: Diagram]

Does $-//-$ sign between trpR and P indicate separation of the trpR gene from the operon? Or could the sign mean that the trpR gene may be present adjacent or far away from the operon, both the possibilities?

Comment: I think that means they are omitting a large section of DNA in between the trpR and P sections. You see a similar symbol on plot axes when they skip numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike P and O sequences which are literally joined at their ends, the sequences trpR and P are rather distant. The DNA between them is so long, that the limited space of the page prevents a decent proportional representation. So instead of painting a long line of limited-importance strands, the graphic designer choose to omit the part between slashes.

Note that despite the apparent disconnect possibly suggested by the sign -//-, the intervening DNA is continuous. The sequences trpR and P are still on the same chromosome.